# Does `yank` mean copying, pasting, or either in Emacs?

Tags: vim, emacs, yank

While `yank` means copying in Vim, I am a bit confused about Emacs. What does `yank` mean there exactly?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1587278/why-does-yank-mean-copying-in-vim-and-pasting-in-emacs

Comment: Yes, it was also my post but I did not get any answer there and for an unknown reason, it was closed so I changed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs uses `yank` to reinsert the last `kill` into the buffer. So it is effectively a paste, rather than a cut or copy.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingAndYanking
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Yanking.html